# Variables that can be echoed

Tags: php

I created a function to know if I can pass a variable to the language structure `echo` with a useful output (for example, arrays output `Array`, which I do not see as useful).

```
function echo_able($var) {
    if (is_string($var)) return true;
    if (is_numeric($var)) return true;
    if (is_object($var) && method_exists($var, '__toString')) return true;
    return false;
}
```

Is there any other types that I forgot?

Because PHP is a bit messy, I can not find a way to know for sure what types of variable can be echoed.

The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/echo) doesn't list what can be echoed.

Comment: Why do you even want to do that?

Comment: `string are not objects but arrays are`?!? No, arrays aren't objects, arrays are arrays

Comment: @Rizier123 Error management

Comment: @MarkBaker My bad. But you still cannot create an object called Array.

Comment: No, you can't call an object by any reserved word

Comment: Perhaps the docs can help you, they have a list of [all the different datatypes](http://nl1.php.net/manual/en/language.types.php): understanding the different datatypes is a good first step toward learning what you can and can't do with them

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you for this link. It seems that my function is *complete* for my usage.

Comment: Not that complete, you've forgotten Boolean, and technically you can echo a null as well

Comment: `for my usage`, I know booleans can be outputted, but they are as `0` or `1`, which could be seen as integers or strings. I realise now that I should create my `output()` function to have everything as I want it to be. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why you don't to use `var_dump()`, `var_export()` or `print_r()` instead of `echo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any variable can be echoed.  When you do that, the content will be converted to string, using language rules. The problem is not that you can't echo something, but maybe that you do not get the result that you want.
You just need to pay attention to what type of conversion will happen by default and if it is what you want.

Edit:
Looks like the objects can not be converted to string unless there is a `__toString` method implementation.
From the  manual, you can see that the behavior was changed.

> It is worth noting that before PHP 5.2.0 the __toString() method was only called when it was directly combined with echo or print. Since PHP 5.2.0, it is called in any string context (e.g. in printf() with %s modifier) but not in other types contexts (e.g. with %d modifier). Since PHP 5.2.0, converting objects without __toString() method to string would cause E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR.

Comment: `Any variable can be echoed` NO, you can't *simply* print an array or an object!

Comment: Have you ever tried to echo an array? It gives you a beautiful `Notice: Array to string conversion`. I understand it is *only* a notice, but still, the echoed text is `Array`, which is, in 99% of the cases, useless. Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: Maybe you should update your question to detail your extra constraints @forever. You've just asked for a list of variable types that can be echoed, which arrays can; it now sounds like you want a list of variable types which provide something "useful" when echoed instead. That's information that would be best in the question rather than buried in a comment

Comment: @Clive *which arrays can* NO, you will get a E_NOTICE!

Comment: @Rizier123 You seem to be confusing the word _can_ for the word _should_. You _can_ echo an array, hence the ability to `echo [];`. I'm not saying you _should_, or that it produces anything useful.

Comment: I don't know how else to explain it @Rizier123. Of course you can echo an array, every PHP dev knows that. You just don't get anything useful out of it.

Comment: @Clive Please post an online script (e.g. http://3v4l.org or http://ideone.com) where you print an array with: *the language structure echo*!

Comment: No, you can do that yourself @Rizier123. Open a php file and type `echo [];`. Then execute it and inspect the output, which will be the word `Array`. Done.

Comment: @Clive Yes if you have error reporting turned off, otherwise you will get a nice: `Notice: Array to string conversion`! That you get `Array` as output after it, is because how PHP handles the error, but it is still wrong!

Comment: @  Rizier123 Is obvious that you should not do it. The point is that if you do it, it happens when you debug something and it happens to be an array. And you do not use var_dump, for whatever reason. Or print_r().

Comment: No it's not wrong @Rizier123, otherwise you wouldn't be able to do it. I'm done arguing now, if you won't accept that an array variable can be echoed that's your concern, not mine

Comment: @forever It is a notice, and it converts the variable to a string the best that it can. I expect that there are no cases when people print random junk from variables they have no idea what they can hold. You may echo an array when you get data from someplace and you do not know what it is, but also, you do not want code execution to stop just because you used an echo statement.

Comment: @OvidiuBadita 1. *It is a notice* Yes and PHP does not just throw a notice out of fun. 2. *the best that it can* Yes maybe but it's just the type; it can't print the actual data of the array 3. *Any variable can be echoed* -> http://3v4l.org/JodNm here you even get a fatal error! So you can't just print any variable with `echo`

Comment: *Looks like the objects can not be converted to string* And I though your said **any** ?

Comment: @Rizier123 I was wrong. I am sorry about that. I knew that the method __toString() is called on objects, but I did not expect to have an error thrown when it is absent.

Answer (score 1):

You can basically use [`gettype()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php) which can return the following possible values:

- "boolean"
- "integer"
- "double"
- "string"
- "array"
- "object"
- "resource"
- "NULL"
- "unknown type".

Maybe you can think of `switch()` statement based on the above possible values, like:

```
switch(gettype($var)) {
  'boolean':
  'integer':
  // ...
    return true;
  default:
    return false;
}
```

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but normally you should use `print_r()`, `var_dump()` or `echo var_export()` to print variables which are not printable.